# Export colums containing (geo)JSON elements to CSV while keeping the JSON double quotes properly

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I want to export using [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html) 5 columns of a table, 3 of them contain ID, text and timestamp values but 2 of them contain JSON and GeoJSON elements, e.g.:

```json
 // Please, note the non-quoted string Value1
 // when there is no space in the value itself:
{"key": "value with space", "other_key": Value1, ...}
```

but when using this command:

```sql
psql \
  -d <connection_uri> \
  --command "\copy public.mytable (id, json_array, geojson_field, status, timestamp) TO './file.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"' ;"
```

The result looks strange:

```bash
11784,"{'"First value'",'"Second value'", ThirdValue, '"Fourth val'",...
```

i.e. it's placing quote in a strange order: "single-double <field_value> single-double"

(also I don't get the headers...)

I wish I could end with a true JSON object in the csv file that I can copy/paste in a validator, e.g. [here](https://jsonformatter.org/) without errors.

Am I doing something wrong?
If yes, how to fix it?

PG:13

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using it this way, using [`FORCE_QUOTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html), which actually works by placing 2 double quotes around the JSON keys and values where needed:

```sh
psql -d <connection_uri> \
  --command "\copy public.mytable (id, json_array, geojson_field, status, timestamp) TO './file.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING 'UTF8', QUOTE '\"', FORCE_QUOTE (json_array, geojson_field));"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 copy t_jsonb to STDOUT (FORMAT CSV, QUOTE ' ', header true);
```

Comment: I went into a strange error: `ERROR: relation "t_jsonb" does not exist`

Comment: Yes, very strange.  Perhaps you have no table "t_jsonb" and yours is called "mytable"?